# Job for etcd.service failed when install tensor flow server model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tenser flow on ubuntu according to the tensor flow official document, after i Add TensorFlow Serving distribution URI as a package source, then run installation, i meet this problem:

```
 apt-get update && apt-get install tensorflow-model-server
Hit:1 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports bionic-proposed InRelease
Hit:4 https://mirrors.aliyun.com/kubernetes/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
tensorflow-model-server is already the newest version (2.1.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 214 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up etcd-server (3.2.17+dfsg-1) ...
Job for etcd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status etcd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript etcd, action "start" failed.
● etcd.service - etcd - highly-available key value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-05-19 20:02:47 CST; 17ms ago
     Docs: https://github.com/coreos/etcd
           man:etcd
  Process: 54294 ExecStart=/usr/bin/etcd $DAEMON_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 54294 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 19 20:02:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting etcd - highly-available key value store...
May 19 20:02:47 ubuntu etcd[54294]: etcd on unsupported platform without ETCD_UNSUPPORTED_ARCH=arm64 set.
May 19 20:02:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: etcd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 19 20:02:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: etcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 19 20:02:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start etcd - highly-available key value store.
dpkg: error processing package etcd-server (--configure):
 installed etcd-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of etcd:
 etcd depends on etcd-server; however:
  Package etcd-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package etcd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 etcd-server
 etcd
```

Answer (score 0):

i modified etcd.service file to add the environment value ETCD_UNSUPPORTED_ARCH=arm64, the issue is solved, but still etcd server can not start, which promote 
"listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: bind: address already in use", i still try to fix this new issue.